# Responsive jumbotron image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a jumbo tron image in my background but it's not as responsive AND the big thing is i can get the whole image to show. Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

And here is the full image:

[image]

Here is my html code of the jumbotron

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 banner">
            <h2><span class="text-red">Lyfe</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>


    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: " Enter Delivery Address", class: "form-control text-center", id: "autohome" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is CSS code

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(IMG-1373.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 130%;
  right: 121px;
}
```

Comment: you can use `img tag` for that, or you can use `background-size: contain;` but it cant solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is full width and your image is in portrait mode, so you can not show the entire image.  Try something like this:

```
.jumbotron {
   background-position: center 20%;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

If you want to have a full screen jumbotron try:

```
.jumbotron {
   height: 100vh;
   background-position: center 20%;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

so you will have the most information of your photo shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your picture is in portrait mode. 
Maybe a 
`background-size: contain;`

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jumbotron class as follows:

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(IMG-1373.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  right: 121px;
}
```

Also take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/) as it is an industry standard for responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size` to get your desired output. I have given width-100% and height-100% here:

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdPCQ.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.text-red{
  color: tomato;
}

.btn {
  background-color: tomato !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 banner">
      <h2><span class="text-red">Lyfe</span></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Enter Delivery Address">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
      <button class="form-control btn">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```